# how to make ie8 support css3 animation feature

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

guys

I have a problem: i need css style —— animation: spin 1s infinite linear; to works in ie8 and ie9.

The style is for ajax loading animation, you know, it's spinning all the way until ajax request finished.

I searched, but i haven't get the solution.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These browsers do not support this CSS3 features. The safest way around this problem is to find a polyfill or use jQuery. But to support rotations in IE8, you would have to use the Matrix Filter, which is not fun.

My recommendation is to use an animated gif for this loading animation. It is simple and effective. Else you could take a look at http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

He explains ways of using the Matrix Filter